# In diesem Satz “Dann sieht es nicht aus wie auf einem Flohmarkt”. Warum steht die Vorsilbe nicht am Ende?

Tags: separable-verb

I have encountered this sentence while studying:

> Dann sieht es nicht aus wie auf einem Flohmarkt

I remember there is a rule for Separate Verbs in present tense saying that the first part of the verb must be separated and placed at the end of the sentence but this is not applied on the above sentence as the part "aus" placed at the middle of the sentence.

Is it correct to write it this way?

> Dann sieht es nicht wie auf einem Flohmarkt aus

Is there a difference in the meaning between the two sentences?

**Edited**: Here is the full text about "Wohnungseinrichtung"

> Weniger ist mehr! Stellen Sie nur wenige Urlaubs-Souvenirs auf ein Regal oder auf einen Schrank. Dann sieht es nicht aus wie auf einem Flohmarkt

Comment: I have updated the question with the full text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants are correctly and practically there's no difference in this case.  *Wie auf einem Flohmarkt* functions as an adverbial phrase, in one case modifying the verb *aussehen*, in the other case the whole sentence.

First, compare:

- *Die Sonne geht schnell auf*: *schnell* modifies *aufgehen*
- *Die Sonne [geht [wie gestern] auf]*: *wie gestern* modifies *aufgehen*
- *[Die Sonne geht auf] [wie gestern]*: *wie gestern* modifies *die Sonne geht auf*.
- *Wie gestern geht die Sonne auf*: not clear, whether *wie gestern* modifies *die Sonne geht auf* or *aufgehen*

Interestingly, an adjective used as an adverb can modify the sentence only in the beginning, not the end: you can say *schnell geht die Sonne auf*, but not **die Sonne geht auf schnell*.  This leads me to conclude that adjective-adverbs cannot modify sentences.

Additionally, the adverbial phrase can also just seem to modify the preposition: *die Sonne geht auf wie gestern, und unter wie vorgestern*.

Now, in your specific case, *aussehen* is more complicated and has a special idiomatic structure: it requires an adverbial phrase as an argument. With *wie*, this phrase can take both of the slots, as shown above (you cannot say something like *Hier sieht es aus.*, unless in special elliptic constructions):

- *Es sieht [wie auf einem Flohmarkt] aus*
- *Es sieht aus [wie auf einem Flohmarkt]*

But you can also have other adverbials:

- *Es sieht aus [als ob das ein Flohmarkt wäre]*
- *Es sieht [nach einem Flohmarkt] aus*
- *Es sieht [ganz gut] aus*

Here, the other position in all cases would be wrong.

Comment: *Die Sonne geht schnell auf* would be perfectly legal, however.